# Capture Azure MFA enrollment event

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, power-automate, multi-factor-authentication

I am looking to automate adding a user to an Azure AD group when he/she enrolls into MFA using the http://aka.ms/mfasetup wizard.

```
When: User enrolls into MFA
Action: Add user to Azure AD Security Group "0000_People_with_MFA"
```

I looked at Microsoft Power Automate but there does not appear to be any triggers from Azure AD. I can perhaps use a webhook or something to call a PowerShell script running on Azure Functions, but there needs to be some way of capturing this event.

Alternatively I can run something from Azure Functions to query AAD every 10 or 15 minutes to add users, but I do not know how to go about that approach either. In pseudo-code it would look something like this:

```js
for (let user of query("SELECT userPrincipalName FROM users WHERE mfaEnabled = 1"))
    addToAADGroup("0000_People_with_MFA", user)
```

Any ideas on how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these PowerShell cmdlets to get list of users with MFA Enabled:

`Install-Module MSOnline` If the module is not installed already.

`Connect-MsolService` Login with Global Admin account.

`Get-MsolUser -All | select DisplayName,BlockCredential,UserPrincipalName,@{N="MFA Status"; E={ if( $_.StrongAuthenticationRequirements.State -ne $null){ $_.StrongAuthenticationRequirements.State} else { "Disabled"}}}` To get a list of users with MFA Enabled

Then you can use `Add-AzureADGroupMember` to add the users to the group. You can also [add the users to a CSV file and bulk add them to a group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/groups-bulk-import-members). (See [also](https://winhoven.com/powershell-azure-ad-v2-0-add-a-list-of-users-to-a-group/).)

I would also recommend checking out the Graph API, where you can query a list of user registration details. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/credentialuserregistrationdetails?view=graph-rest-beta

Comment: I've gotten this to work locally, but is there a way to do it with Azure Functions? It took me more than a day to get the "hello world" running but the PowerShell on Azure doesn't seem to support the `MSOnline` nor `AzureAD` modules. Or perhaps there is another solution that would allow me to run the script on Azure on a timed interval?